# How to make a timer like digital watch?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make digital watch in excel. So, when I will open a workbook then in a cell, lets say in `E3` cell will show time and it will continue in every second so that it looks like a digital watch. I can do it in `Access` as access `Form` has `On Timer` event where I can write code to show time in a `Textbox`. Is there any alternative way in excel. I have tried below codes. But the codes need to click manually on `Button1`. Can I make it automatic to run the `Button1_Click()` sub in every second?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.OnTime Now(), "RunningTime"
End Sub

Sub RunningTime()
    Range("E3") = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

**I have also tried `Workbook_Open()` method but it runs once when I open the file.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now(), "RunningTime"
End Sub
```

Comment: No direct way as there is no timer control event in excel so far my best known. But you can apply some tricks to achieve that in a `VBA` coding way.

Comment: @harun24hr Can you please show me the trick? I tried different way but fail to do that. I will be grateful to you if you help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve it but you can apply some tricks to do that. First put below codes to a `Module`.

```
Public Times As Boolean

Sub TimerRun()
    If Not Times Then Exit Sub
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "TimerRun"
    Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")
End Sub

Sub TimerStop()
    Times = False
End Sub
```

**Then copy below codes and paste in `Workbook_Open()` event.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Range("E3").Value = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    Times = True
    TimerRun
End Sub
```

If you want to make start or stop button so that you can start/stop timer manually by clicking on a button then put a form control command button and then assign `TimerRun` sub to start and assign `TimerStop` to stop timer.

Comment: Do I need to manually trigger any button to run timer or it will automatically show time after opening the file?

Comment: You do not need to trigger anything manually. It will automatically starts to show times in `E3` cell. If you want to stop then you need to trigger `TimerStop()` sub manually.

Comment: The codes work for me. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.